# redirect url exact match with htaccess like case sensitive

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

redirect url exact match with htaccess not redirect if query string or anything after index.php

```
Redirect This Page: https://example.com/demo/index.php
To Page: https://example.com/ (home page)

But Do Not redirect: https://example.com/demo/index.php/*

 Do NOT redirect: https://example.com/demo/index.php/password

 Do NOT redirect https://example.com/demo/index.php?m=page
  not redirect if any other combination 

only redirect https://example.com/demo/index.php to https://example.com/
```

this script not working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^demo/index.php /demo/index.php?m=page[L,NC,END]
RewriteRule ^demo/index.php$ https://example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: If the second rule is not working as expected you are either looking at a cached result in your browser or the rewriting module is not enabled for that host or location. How did you enable the interpretation of distributed configuration files (".htaccess") and how did you make sure they are considered now?

Comment: rewriting module is enable other redirect working well. i have test on other site there is no cache and there is also not working

Comment: Ah, if you have multiple such rules (why did you not show _all_ of them?), then it might be a question of the order of the rules. Keep in mind that rules are processed from top to bottom. If you stop the rewriting process before that rule is considered it indeed will not get applied...

Comment: Your question is really not clear at all. If you want to redirect `https://example.com/demo/index.php` ONLY to `https://example.com/` then only set ONE rule `RewriteRule ^demo/index.php$ https://example.com/ [L,R=301]`

Comment: this rule removing just index.php   demo/index.php redirect to demo/

Answer (score 0):

> only redirect `https://example.com/demo/index.php` to `https://example.com/`

If you only want to redirect that *exact* URL, without a query string then you need to reverse your existing rules and include an additional condition that checks that the QUERY_STRING is empty. The `RewriteRule` only matches against the URL-path, which excludes the query string.

You are also missing a *space* before the flags argument in the first rule.

For example:

```
# Redirect exact URL to home page
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^demo/index\.php$ / [R=302,L]

# Redirect other URLs with query string OR path-info
RewriteRule ^demo/index\.php /demo/index.php?m=page [NC,L]
```

You don't need `L` *and* `END`.

Test with 302, and change to 301 only once you have confirmed it works OK. To avoid caching issues.

Comment: this script just removing index.php  demo/index.php?asda=das redirect to demo/?asda=das

Comment: this is working well redirectMatch 301 ^/client/index.php$ https://example.com/ but not working with query string like client/index.php?dd=dfd

Comment: This is what the first rule does in my answer. (If you don't need the rewrite (2nd rule) - you make no mention of this in your question - then remove it?) You can't match the query string with a mod_alias `RedirectMatch` directive, you need to use a mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` (as above) to match against the query string (in order to confirm the query string is empty).

Answer (score 0):

You may use these rules in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+demo/index\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^demo/index\.php$ $0?m=page [QSA,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This was created by [htaccess redirect generator](https://www.301-redirect.online/htaccess-rewrite-generator) I use very often.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^demo/index\.php$ https://example.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Maybe "?" sign is redundant because of empty query string match.

Not sure, but You also can try to add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
```

in case You can't log in. All together:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^demo/index\.php$ https://example.com/? [R=301,L]
```